# How to scale several Jetpack Compose elements together and in respect to the screen's/a parent's constraints?

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I've currently finished the [Dice Roller app tutorial](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-build-a-dice-roller-app) from the official Android course, having this code:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.wrapContentSize
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.tl.dicetut.ui.theme.DiceTutTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            DiceTutTheme{
                DiceRollerApp()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun DiceRollerApp() {
    DiceWithButtonAndImage(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center)
    )
}

@Composable
fun DiceWithButtonAndImage(modifier: Modifier = Modifier){
    var result: Int by remember { mutableStateOf(1) }
    val imageResource = when (result) {
        1 -> R.drawable.dice_1
        2 -> R.drawable.dice_2
        3 -> R.drawable.dice_3
        4 -> R.drawable.dice_4
        5 -> R.drawable.dice_5
        else -> R.drawable.dice_6
    }
    Column(
        modifier = modifier,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ){
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(imageResource),
            contentDescription = result.toString(),
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        Button(onClick = {result = (1..6).random()}) {
            Text(stringResource(id = R.string.roll))
        }
    }
}
```

This results in this render:
[image: Dice 1]

From what I understand after testing different parameters, .fillMax.. sets the constraints of the element, so this portion of the code:

```
.fillMaxSize()
.wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center)
```

which goes to the Column composable tells the column to set the constraints to the entire screen and to align its children to the center of the constraints.

The xml files of the dice images set their width and height to 200dp x 250dp, which results in the current rendering size. Setting the image to a Modifier.FillMaxWidth() + a ContentScale.Crop seems to scale the dp until both axes are either equal to or larger than their respective constraint, so it does the trick of scaling the dice up to the screen's width, but it of course doesn't scale the button together with the dice image and thus doesn't retain their initial proportions to each other.

The only way I found so far to scale both of these composable elements together was to use Modifier.scale(float) on the column, but that doesn't seem to provide a way to scale specifically in respect to the screen's constraints.

What is the correct way of doing such joint scaling?